# Set the height of parent node to 1 in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

I have a parent node and multiple child nodes within.

I want to set the parent node height to 1 and child node heights to 1, so that when arranging all the child nodes linearly, both parent and child node together will look like a line with dots.

I am able to set child nodes height and width to 1, so they appear as dots. But the parent node height doesn't change, whether I set 1 or 100.

This is the current output that I get:
[image]

Expected output:
[image]

I believe it is something to do with parent nodes. Isn't it possible to set the height of parent nodes?

Comment: You cannot set the height of a parent node, but you can set the padding of the parent node to 0 (default is 10). But even in that case I think there will be a small padding (1px) inherently from the base code of cytoscape.js.